# (Sub-)Gaussian Norm Concentration Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure

I am looking for a proof of the following: Let $X_1 \dots, X_n $ be i.i.d. $N(\mu, \Sigma)$, then
$$
\mathbb{P} \left ( \|\bar{X}_n-\mu \|_{2} > \sqrt{\frac{\text{Tr}\Sigma}{n}}+\sqrt{\frac{2 \| \Sigma \| \log(1/\delta)}{n}}   \right ) \le \delta
$$
where $\|\Sigma \|$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$. This holds generally for any sub-Gaussian random variables. I am not sure how to get the $\| \Sigma\|$ term - I'm just looking for a hint or a good reference here.

Comment: Where does this inequality come from?

Comment: @IgorRivin see this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.07425 on the second page for example, it is stated as if it is a very standard result without a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show $$P(\|X_1 - \mu\|_2 > \sqrt{\text{Tr} \Sigma} + \sqrt{2 \|\Sigma\| \log(1/\delta)}) \le \delta.$$ (Since $\bar{X}_n$ is also [sub-]Gaussian with mean $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma/n$, replacing $X_1$ with $\bar{X}_n$ and $\Sigma$ with $\Sigma/\sqrt{n}$ gives the stated result.)

Without loss of generality, we can also assume $\mu=0$.

Theorem 6.3.2 and Exercise 6.3.5 in [Vershynin's book](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) seem relevant. Writing $X_1 = \Sigma^{1/2} Z$ where $Z \sim N(0, I)$, the statement in the exercise produces
$$P(\|\Sigma^{1/2} Z\|_2 \ge C \|\Sigma^{1/2}\|_F + t) \le \exp\left(-\frac{ct^2}{\|\Sigma^{1/2}\|^2}\right)$$
where $\|\Sigma^{1/2}\|_F = \sqrt{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)}$ and $\|\Sigma^{1/2}\|^2 = \|\Sigma\|$. I think substituting $\delta =  \exp\left(-\frac{ct^2}{\|\Sigma^{1/2}\|^2}\right)$ and rewriting will produce something like the first line of my post.

(Apologies for the hand-waving; just giving you a sketch and pointer since you are just asking for a hint/reference.)

Comment: thanks - this makes sense, but one thing I am still unsure about is the presence of the constants $c,C$. There doesn't seem to be a way of removing them to get the exact result

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be proved in [Rinaldi's lecture notes.](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Earinaldo/Teaching/36709/S19/Scribed_Lectures/Feb26_Ojash.pdf)

Comment: Those notes establish a result for the concentration of the operator norm of the empirical covariance matrix around the true covariance matrix, but OP's question is about the concentration of the mean vector around the true mean.